# How to list all mp4 files with HDp60 (to separate them from p30)?

Tags: command-line, mp4, batch

I need to separate my mp4 files into p30 and p60 and would like to use command line tools to do this. I know that there is an option to check the details of a media file and I need to do this as a batch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffprobe` for get video [frame rate](http://www.frankschrader.us/video-frame-rates-60i-vs-60p-vs-30p-vs-24p-what-it-means/).

Install: `apt install ffmpeg`

Usage for 1 file:

```sh
ffprobe -v error -select_streams \
v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \
-show_entries stream=r_frame_rate <your-filename>.mp4
```

Get filenames and framerates in batch for all videos in current dir (divided by `\t`):

```bsh
for videofile in *.mp4; do
 echo -n "$videofile\t"
 ffprobe -v error -select_streams v \
 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \
 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate $videofile
```

Get filenames and framerates in batch for all videos in current dir and subdirs using `find`:

```bsh
find -name '*.mp4' -printf '%p\t' \
-exec ffprobe -v error -select_streams \
v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1  \
-show_entries stream=r_frame_rate {} \;
```

Comment: The second option is to be used in a `skript.sh` file? Also, would it make sense to remove the `\` to be able to copy and paste it directly?

Comment: When using the third option I get `Missing argument for -exec`.

Comment: 'to be able to copy and paste it directly': Do you want move files to another dir based on framerate?

Comment: No, I mean to be able to copy and paste your code directly into command line. With the *\\* it seems not possible. (I recognised that the sign I was referring to was not displayed in my first comment.) Please also check my second comment regarding the error. Thanks!

Comment: Try this code. Single line without wraps.  `find -name '*.mp4' -printf '%p\t' -exec ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate {} \;`

Comment: Thanks, I had missed the last backslash.